# What is the physical meaning of "flow" or "circulation" in fluid dynamics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex

In fluid dynamics, the line integral of velocity field is called "flow," or "circulation" if the curve is closed. But does velocity times length correspond to any physically meaningful quantity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\bf v$ represents the velocity field, then the circulation can be rewritten using [Stoke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) as $$\oint_C \bf v\cdot dl=\iint_{S} \nabla \times\mathbf{v} \cdot d\mathbf{S}$$

This quantity can be referred to as the *flux* of the [*vorticity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity), where vorticity $$\mathbf \omega=\nabla\times v$$ is the curl of the velocity. Physically, vorticity flux is a measure of the fluid's angular momentum per unit volume across the surface $S$ enclosed by the path $C$.

For a detailed explanation, see [these](http://www.pmaweb.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2012/1214.1.K.pdf) notes by Caltech where they have a nice analogy between circulation, vorticity and the magnetic field:

*Circulation; it is analogous to magnetic-field flux. In fact, the
analogy with magnetic fields turns out to be extremely useful. Vorticity, like a magnetic field,
automatically has vanishing divergence, which means that the vortex lines are continuous,
just like magnetic field lines. Vorticity, again like a magnetic field, is an axial vector and
thus can be written as the curl of a polar vector potential, the velocity v. Vorticity has the
interesting property that it evolves in a perfect fluid in such a manner that the flow carries
the vortex lines along with it; we say that the vortex lines are “frozen into the fluid”.*

See also [advection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection), which refers to the transport of a substance or by bulk motion of a fluid.

Answer (score 1):

Using Stokes' theorem, the circulation can be related to the fluid **vorticity** as follows:
$$\oint \vec{v}.d\vec{\ell}=\int_S (\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{v}). d \vec{S}$$
The integral on the left hand side is taken along a closed contour $C$. On the right hand side, $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{v}$ is the vorticity of the fluid and $d\vec{S}$ is the fluid surface element spanning the contour $C$.

When combined with **Kelvin's Theorem**, this relationship has a physical consequence. According to this theorem, in an isentropic fluid
$$\frac{d}{dt}\oint \vec{v}.d\vec{\ell} = 0$$
Now let's apply Kelvin's theorem to an infinitesimal closed contour. Using the first equation above, we have:
$$\oint \vec{v}.d\vec{\ell} \simeq (\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{v}). d \vec{S}= \text{constant}$$
Since $C$ is infinitesimal, it acts like a fluid element (don't confuse it with the surface "element" mentioned above). This result can then be interpreted as that the vorticity (in an isentropic fluid) moves with the fluid.

Comment: You can find similar things on page 13, Fluid Mechanics by Landau-Lifshitz  (Vol6). I just tried to repeat the ideas given there.